# Pact implementation in spring-boot starter

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I've started to try and implement pact-framework into a spring-boot-starter and I've stumbled upon a problem. I want it to be possible to configure consumer, producer and so on over application.properties. At the moment I've created three modules `AutoConfigure`, `Starter`, and `Sample`. In the sample I'm trying to implement a consumer. When I look for dependency:tree in `Starter` I can see them.

Here is the AutoConfigure implementation:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean({PactProviderRuleMk2.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PactProperties.class)
public class PactAutoConfiguration {

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PactAutoConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
private PactProperties properties;

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public PactProviderRuleMk2 pactProviderRuleMk2() {
        if (this.properties.getProvider().getName() == null
            || this.properties.getProvider().getHost() == null
            || this.properties.getProvider().getPort() == 0)
        {
            String msg = "PactProviderRuleMk2 properties not configured properly." +
                " Please check test.pact.provider.* properties settings in configuration file.";
            log.error(msg);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }

        PactProviderRuleMk2 mockProvider = new PactProviderRuleMk2(
                this.properties.getProvider().getName(),
                this.properties.getProvider().getHost(),
                this.properties.getProvider().getPort(),
                this);

        return mockProvider;
    }
}
```

When I debbug the `ConsumerPortTest` I get the `rule` initialized, but without the `pacts (which is size=0) and without`mockServer`which is`null`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ConsumerPortTest {

    @Rule
    @Autowired
    // public PactProviderRuleMk2 rule = new PactProviderRuleMk2("Foo_Provider", "localhost", 8080, this);
    public PactProviderRuleMk2 rule;

    @Pact(provider="Foo_Provider", consumer="Foo_Consumer")
    public RequestResponsePact createFragment(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        return builder.uponReceiving("a request for Foos")
                .path("/foos")
                    .method("GET")
                    .willRespondWith()
                    .status(200)
                    .body("[{\"value\":42}, {\"value\":100}]")
                .toPact();
    }

    @Test
    @PactVerification("Foo_Provider")
    public void runTest() {
        ConsumerPort consumerPort = new ConsumerPort(rule.getConfig().url());
        assertThat("Response JSON body has to have values 42 and 100!",
                consumerPort.foos(),
                is(Arrays.asList(new Foo(42), new Foo(100))));
    }
}
```

And here is the link to the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/cotnic/pact-spring-boot-starter) I've commited to. All the help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!